# Switch MX entry to main domain – Dovecot user issue

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, dovecot

I tried switching my MX record from the subdomain mail.mydomain.com to mydomain.com. Updating the Postfix and Dovecot configuration (SSL certs, hostname etc) worked mostly fine. Most e-mail addresses are used to forward mail, but there is a single (virtual) mailbox user managed by Dovecot. The username is mailer@mydomain.com, and his mail is stored at /var/mail/virtual/mailer@mydomain.com.

After changing the rest of the configuration, sending messages to mailer@mydomain.com (or one of its alias addresses) results in a Postfix error message:

```
<mailer@mydomain.com> (expanded from <postmaster@mydomain.com>): unknown user: "mailer"
```

In Postfix's main.cf, I have

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = mydomain.com
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/mailbox_users
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

and `mailbox_users` contains a single line

```
mailer@mydomain.com OK
```

Postfix seems to look for a system user now (without the domain), not the Dovecot user mailer@mydomain.com – which Dovecot/Postfix settings should be changed to solve this problem?

Thanks,
Jan

Comment: Did you modify `mailbox_users`? If yes, did you run `postmap` on it?

Comment: Thank you – I found the solution (s. below).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: I had not changed the value of `mydestination` for Postfix, which included the updated `myhostname` (mydomain.com), so there was an overlap between `mydestination` and the `virtual_mailbox_domains`.